# What is the difference between creating a new object inside select LINQ clause and inside a method

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I have an entity class which is mapped to an SQL table:

```
public class EntityItem {

 public virtual ICollection<EntityItem2> SomeItems { get; set; }

}
```

And I have the following two snippets:

```
var items = _repository.Table.Where(x => x.Id == id)
                        .Select(x => new ItemModel {
                                     Items = x.SomeItems.Select(y => new SomeItem { //mapping is here...}).ToList() 
                               });
```

And

```
var items = _repository.Table.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => someModelMapper.BuildModel(x));

//inside a mapper
public ItemModel BuildModel(EntityType entity){

    var model = new ItemModel();
    model.Items = entity.SomeItems.Select(x => anotherMapper.BuildModel(x));

    return model;
}
```

As a result, I am getting different SQL queries in both cases. Moreover, the second snippet is working much slower than the first one. As I can see in SQL profiler the second snipper is generating many SQL queries.
So my questions:

1. Why is that happening?
2. How to create new objects like in the second snippet but to avoid
   lots of SQL queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely reason you are seeing a difference in performance is due to EF Core materializing the query prematurely.  When a Linq statement is compiled, EF attempts to translate it into SQL. If you call a function within the expression, EF6 would have raised an exception to the effect that the method cannot be converted to SQL.  EF Core tries to be clever, and when it encounters a method it cannot convert, it executes the query up to the point it could get to, and then continues to execute the rest as Linq2Object where you method can run. IMO this is a pretty stupid feature and represents a huge performance landmine, and while it's fine to offer it as a possible option, it should be disabled by default.

You're probably seeing extra queries due to lazy loading after the main query runs, to populate the view models in the mapping method.

For instance if I execute:

```
var results = context.Parents.Select(x => new ParentViewModel
{
    ParentId = x.ParentId,
    Name = x.Name,
    OldestChildName = x.Children.OrderByDescending(c => c.BirthDate).Select(c => c.Name).FirstOrDefault() ?? "No Child"
}).Single(x => x.ParentId == parentId);
```

That would execute as one statement.  Calling a method to populate the view model:

```
var results = context.Parents 
    .Select(x => buildParentViewModel(x))
    .Single(x => x.ParentId == parentId);
```

would execute something like:

```
var results = context.Parents
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new ParentViewModel
    {
        ParentId = x.ParentId,
        Name = x.Name,
        OldestChildName = x.Children.OrderByDescending(c => c.BirthDate).Select(c => 
c.Name).FirstOrDefault() ?? "No Child"
    }).Single(x => x.ParentId == parentId);
```

at worst or:

```
var results = context.Parents
    .Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId)
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new ParentViewModel
    {
        ParentId = x.ParentId,
        Name = x.Name,
        OldestChildName = x.Children.OrderByDescending(c => c.BirthDate).Select(c => 
c.Name).FirstOrDefault() ?? "No Child"
    }).Single();
```

... at best. These are due to the Extra `.ToList()` call prior to the Select which is roughly what the premature execution will do automatically. The issue with these queries compared to the first one is that when it comes to loading the child's name. In the first query, the SQL generated pulls the parent and related child's details in one query. In the alternative cases the query will execute to pull the parent's details, but getting the child details will constitute a lazy load call to get more details since that will be executed as Linq2Object.

The solution would be to use Automapper and it's built in `ProjectTo` method to populate your view model. This will place the mapping code in automatically so that it works like the first scenario without you needing to write out all of the mapping code.

Comment: In EFCore 3 the behavior is to throw an error stating it cannot be translated and requires the query to be materialized.

Comment: Cool, a step back in the right direction. I've just had a read of that breaking change and the `Select` can still trigger a client-side evaluation (Where as `Where` and such evaluations will now throw exceptions) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client So the above looks like it would still apply as a potential problem in EF Core 3 if the `Select` population is handed off method wants to rely on lazy loads.